# How to Disable V8's Optimizing Compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8, compiler-optimization

I'm writing a constant-time string comparison function (for node.js) and would like to disable V8's optimizing compiler for this single function; using command-line flags are out of the question.

I know that using a `with{}` (or try/catch) block will disable the optimizing compiler *now*, but I'm afraid this "feature" (bug) will be fixed in future versions.

Is there an immutable (and documented) way disabling V8's optimizing compiler?

---

Example function:

```
function constantTimeStringCompare( a, b ) {
    // By adding a `with` block here, we disable v8's optimizing compiler.
    // Using Object.create(null) ensures we don't have any object prototype properties getting in our way.our way.
    with ( Object.create( null ) ){
        var valid = true,
            length = Math.max( a.length, b.length );
        while ( length-- ) {
            valid &= a.charCodeAt( length ) === b.charCodeAt( length );
        }
        // returns true if valid == 1, false if valid == 0
        return !!valid;
    }
}
```

And a [perf test](http://jsperf.com/constant-time-and-v8-optimizing-compiler) just for fun.

Comment: A constant-time comparison with a `while` loop in it ... ಠ_ಠ (maybe that's not the real approach?)

Comment: ... also how would "valid" ever be anything other than a boolean? Maybe I'm paying too much attention to the code :)

Comment: The `constant` part is relevant to the input strings' lengths. Perhaps I should just return false if the lengths don't match. I don't see the problem with the `while` loop though.

Comment: `valid` is actually either `0` or `1` here, unless length is 0.

Comment: Well "constant-time" means "independent of input details", but I won't infringe on your right to re-interpret that. And yes I guess the "valid" thing will work fine; I didn't think about the binary operators converting `true` to a number.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch That's called linear time, since the execution time as a function of the input length is a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function). Also this function is probably *worse* than builtin string comparison - you're missing **three** very common shortcuts.

Comment: Any user function is always worse because user function cannot do identity comparisons.

Comment: @Pointy and @millimoose: if string `a` was ALWAYS the same string, and string `b` was never longer than string `a`, would this function be considered "constant-time"? (ignore `Math.max` string `length` check, for the time being)

Comment: @millimoose, do you mean "worse" as in slower? Speed is of no importance here (actually, being slow may even be a feature). As for the shortcuts, if I am going for constant (or linear) time, wouldn't I want to avoid all shortcuts anyway?

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Your first question is a very contrived scenario. Generally the "value" of the run-time function is how many times a given operation is executed given an input of size `n`. In your case, this operation would be the character comparison. Since this would be the length of the **longer** string, it doesn't matter that `a` is constant, since for all strings `b` longer than `a` the value of this function would be `b.length`. (Since there is an infinite amount of strings longer than `a`, and a finite number of strings shorter than `a`, we can ignore the shorter ones in our analysis.)

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Also, for algorithm complexity, you generally consider asymptotic complexity. The shortcut that checks for reference equality can be disregarded here. The other I can remember now is checking whether the lengths are equal, which is a constant-time check assuming string lengths are known beforehand. (As is the case in Javascript.) Meaning that a function that uses it would be constant-time for inputs of inequal length, and linear-time for inputs of equal length. So yes, in this case leaving out those checks would guarantee that your function is *linear-time* for all strings.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Whereas with those shortcuts, it would be *constant-time* theoretically for most pairs of strings and linear for an infinitesimal subset of all pairs of strings. Practically, it would depend on your range of inputs. Even without them as you've noticed the function wouldn't be perfectly linear because of the overhead of `.length` and `max()`

Comment: @millimoose, I've rewritten the constantTimeStringCompare function here: http://jsfiddle.net/musicisair/tm6NS/2/. It is still a little contrived, but that is okay for this scenario. Can you take a look at this and let me know if you still think it isn't constant-time?

Comment: @DavidMurdoch It is. [It's also incorrect.](http://jsfiddle.net/millimoose/xuxDM/1/) Your function determines whether `a` is a prefix of `b`. (To make this a constant-time comparison, you'd in fact have to implement the "optimisations" I've mentioned.) Also counting all operations into counter makes no sense. You usually count the instances of one or sometimes several "representative" operations, separately. Reads or writes to input elements (in your case characters) are common, as are comparisons between input elements. You can safely ignore constant overhead.

Comment: Woops! Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/musicisair/tm6NS/3/ (I think)

Comment: @millimoose, FYI: Checking the length of very long string doesn't seem to take any more time than checking the length of a short string. http://jsperf.com/nan-vs-number-comparison (ignore the URL's slug, it is wrong)

Comment: @DavidMurdoch I've said as much before though. You're not checking the length of a string, in Javascript it's an explicitly stored number unlike with C's zero-terminated strings.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Yes, checking whether the lengths are equal would fix it. In that case however you're just doing pointless busywork comparing the characters when the lengths aren't equal, even though you know the strings can't be equal. Which I guess is something you want for some reason. Do note however that if `b` is shorter than `a`, the internal code path to return a `null` when you try to read a character past its end might take a different time than when it does reading a character that is there.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch And in fact, reading past the end of a string seems to be very noticeably slower: http://jsperf.com/reading-past-the-end-of-a-string. So your function still won't really be constant-time since the length of `b` matters for strings shorter than `a`. (Although theoretically, there aren't many of those compared to the set of all possible strings.)

Comment: Can you explain *why* you'd possibly want to disable optimisations?

Comment: @millimoose, I fixed that as well: http://jsperf.com/constant-time-string-comparison. It just doesn't support empty strings now.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg By now I'm morbidly fascinated by the tricks he comes up with to make the function do the same amount of busywork regardless of input size, so I guess entertaiment value would be an explanation.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: this started as an attempt at preventing timing attacks against a password validation function in node.js, and has morphed into an exercise in algorithmic complexity and computer science. The conversation in these comments has nothing to do with my original question. Let's continue this is chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36424/o1

Comment: @millimoose pretty much. :-) Let's continue this is chat: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36424/o1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want solid way to do it, you need to run node with `--allow-natives-syntax` flag and call this:

```
%NeverOptimizeFunction(constantTimeStringCompare);
```

Note that you should call this before you have called `constantTimeStringCompare`, if the function is already optimized then this violates an assertion.

Otherwise `with` statement is your best bet as making it optimizable would be absolute lunacy whereas supporting `try/catch` would be reasonable. You don't need it to affect your code though, this will be sufficient:

```
function constantTimeStringCompare( a, b ) {
    with({});

    var valid = true,
        length = Math.max( a.length, b.length );
    while ( length-- ) {
        valid &= a.charCodeAt( length ) === b.charCodeAt( length );
    }
    // returns true if valid == 1, false if valid == 0
    return !!valid;

}
```

Merely mentioning `with` statement corrupts the entire containing function - the optimizations are done at function-level granularity, not per statement.

Comment: The use of flags is, unfortunately, not an option. I feel as though V8's optimizing compiler may optimize the empty `with` block away, one day. Do you not see this optimization as a potentiality, if not, why?

Comment: @DavidMurdoch There is no optimizations done such as dead code removal because the function disabled optimizations by mentioning `with`. Before such optimization could happen, they would have to start supporting `with` in their optimizing compiler, which I already said would be lunacy in the first place because the philosophy is to support reasonable code. `with` is pure evil and even syntax error in strict mode, not reasonable code that people will hurry to optimize. But it's your best bet if you don't want to use flags.

Comment: 8 years later: a colleague asked me why the debugger couldn't see some variables in a function when technically they should be. I told him I bet it is the optimizing compiler removing them from the scope since they aren't used by the function. I mentioned that long ago someone told me that using `with({}){}` in the function will cause the optimizer to bail -- and it still does today (at least in Node v14.18.2 with a debugger attached). :-)

Answer (score 4):

To actually check is function optimized by particular Node.js version you can refer to [Optimization Killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#optimization-killers) wiki of bluebird.
I've checked 3 solutions on Node 7.2:

1. `with({})` - Function is optimized by TurboFan
2. `try {} catch(e) {}` - Function is optimized by TurboFan
3. `eval('');` - Function is not optimized

**So to guarantee disable V8 optimization you should add `eval('')` to function body.**