# Why is nothing in scope in the protractor debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging, protractor

I'm on OSX, with protractor version 1.3.1 installed. If I put browser.debugger() in my test and run with

$ protractor debug test/protractor.conf.js

I go into the debugger screen. Then I hit "c" and it seems to stop at my breakpoint.
However, nothing seems to be in scope, everything comes up as undefined.

debug> browser
ReferenceError: browser is not defined

If I enter 'repl', I go into a node repl loop (I think?) and I can look at the browser object, but none of my local variables from the test seem to be in scope, they all come up as undefined.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to inspect variables / evaluate code you need to go to repl first. Your variables might be optimised out by v8 if they are not referenced in the current scope. Possible solutions: reference them in code, add `with({})` block, use try/catch or [some other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476402/how-to-disable-v8s-optimizing-compiler)

Comment: Adding with( {} ); above the breakpoint code seems to have no effect. Not sure if the issue is the optimiser?

Answer (score 0):

Your local variables don't show up because `browser.debugger` doesn't pause in the same local scope - what it does is add a command to the control flow queue to debug when the control flow gets there.

This is desirable so that if your test does

```
someElem.click();
browser.debugger();
otherElem.click();
```

That it will pause after the click has occurred, instead of just after it has been scheduled.

You can still use `debugger;` directly if you want to investigate local variables.

Comment: Hi Julie, thanks. for whatever reason when I use the plain npm debugger I just don't get any pause at all, it's just blows through the test. Any idea why that might be?