# Chrome developer tools strange behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I try to play around with scope variable in js and using chrome developer tools. I am trying to acces closure variables, like this:

```
"use strict"

var Dog = function(){                                                                   
  this.color = "brown";                                                             
  this.weight = "10";                                                               
} 

Dog.prototype.generateCode = function(){                                            
  var codeSeparator = "#";               
  var _this = this;

  return label();                                                                   
  function label(){
    debugger;                             
    return _this.color + _this.weight;                              
  }     
}       

var d = new Dog();                            
d.generateCode();
```

When I try to access the variable `codeSeparator` I get an error using chrome developer tools but Firefox is fine with that.

On the other hand, if I use the variable in the function, chrome seems to be fine:

```
  //...                                                        
  function label(){
    debugger;                             
    return _this.color + codeSeparator + _this.weight;                              
  }
```

I am not sure if this is a bug with chrome developer tools or a JS concept I don't get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome's V8 has a feature called `Dead Code Elimination`

If you do not use `codeSeparator` anywhere, V8 may remove this code.

Reference:

- Dead Code Elimination (DCE) — removes the code that does not affect the program results.

https://blog.ghaiklor.com/optimizations-tricks-in-v8-d284b6c8b183
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/roll/src/compiler/dead-code-elimination.cc

Comment: Oh, it makes sense now. Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: I don't know how to disable it dynamically ...  :(  Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476402/how-to-disable-v8s-optimizing-compiler  but it is for Node.js, not for Chrome